# Using xcopy /exclude to exclude .o, but include .odt?

Tags: windows-7, rsync, regex, xcopy

From `xcopy /?`

```
/EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
               Specifies a list of files containing strings.  Each string
               should be in a separate line in the files.  When any of the
               strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be
               copied, that file will be excluded from being copied.  For
               example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
               all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
               .obj extension respectively.
```

But let's say that I want to **EXCLUDE** all `.o` files and **INCLUDE** all `.odt` files. If it was regex, I could use `\.o$`. But it's not, is it?

How do I do it?

(I'm not opposed to using rsync or something else, either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [robocopy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx), the `/xf` switch can be used to exclude specific extensions.

Comment: Since robocopy ships with Windows-7, I'll take a look at it. Thanks for the pointer.